# Point to a javascript array inside a separate file based on a dropdown selection, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I'm currently building a page translation feature using jquery, it works perfectly if all languages are in a single lang.js file, in an array. However, if the project is too huge, with hundreds of languages, this lang.js file will be overloaded, and would need to be decoupled in anyways.

The html code is as follows:

```
<form>
    <label>Select a language:</label>
    <select class="lang-wrapper">
        <option id="en" value="usa">English</option>
        <option id="km" value="india">ខ្មែរ</option>
        <option id="ar" value="arabic">Arabic</option>
    </select>
</form>


<ul>
    <li class="lang" key="home">Home</li>
    <li class="lang" key="about">About Us</li>
    <li class="lang" key="contact">Contact Us</li>
</ul>
<p class="lang" key="desc">This is my description</p>
```

The code to set the language based on the dropdown selection is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("select.lang-wrapper").change(function () {
            var lang = $(this).children("option:selected").attr('id');

            // Will loop as many elements as found on the page with class .lang to translate them
            $('.lang').each(function (index, item) {
                $(this).text(dictionary["homepage"][lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
            });
        });
    });
```

A sample of old js file that holds all languages, mini version.

```
dictionary = {
homepage: {
    en : {
    home: 'Home',
    about: 'About Us',
    contact: 'Contact Us',
    desc : 'This is my description'
    },
    km : {
        home : 'ទំព័រដើម',
        about : 'អំពីយើង',
        contact : 'ទំនាក់ទំនងយើងខ្ញុំ',
        desc : 'នេះគឺជាអត្ថបទរបស់ខ្ញុំ'
    },
    ar : {
        home : 'الصفحة الرئيسية',
        about : 'من نحن',
        contact : 'تواصل معنا',
        desc : 'تفاصيل أكثر'
    }
}
```

}

What I wish to accomplish is having a separate folder for each language, like en.js, ar.js, and ind.js, as an example for en.js version

```
en = {
homepage: {
    en : {
    home: 'Home',
    about: 'About Us',
    contact: 'Contact Us',
    desc : 'This is my description'
    }
}
```

}

Please take note that the dictionary name is changed to the language index, which is en.

My approach was to decouple the languages into files, and then use the next line of code to point to the array that is holding the language as follows.

```
var file = $(this).children("option:selected").attr('id');
```

Point to it like:

```
$(this).text(file["homepage"][lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
```

However, this doesn't work as it considers the file name as an array, not pointing to the array as in the first working snippet with the dictionary in the lang.js file.

Any suggestion to point to different arrays based on the file variable value? So depending on the dropdown selected, it will have an id value that points to a similar name array written in a separate file.

Comment: You need to use AJAX to read from a file on the server.

Comment: You can use `$.getScript()` to execute a script that sets a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest because you organised the language files in json format, you could use the [jQuery getJSON function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to get that data. I'd also recommend to cache the translations locally to be able to reuse them between page views.

The actual translation then has to occur in the callback of the ajax call.

```
// Will loop as many elements as found on the page with class .lang to translate them
function translate(translation) {
  $(".lang").each(function (index, item) {
    $(this).text(translation[$(this).attr("key")]);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  var translations = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("translations")) || {};

  $("select.lang-wrapper").change(function () {
    var lang = $(this).children("option:selected").attr("id");

    if (typeof translations[lang] === "undefined") {
      $.getJSON("src/translations/" + lang + ".json", function (data) {
        translations[lang] = data;
        localStorage.setItem("translations", JSON.stringify(translations));
        translate(translations[lang]);
      });
    } else {
      translate(translations[lang]);
    }
  });
});
```

The Json file would then only contain the inner data structure, like

```
{
  "home": "Home",
  "about": "About Us",
  "contact": "Contact Us",
  "desc": "This is my description"
}
```

For Json to be valid, also keys must be double quoted.

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-curie-d9yc2?file=/index.html

Comment: thanks @charlietfl for pointing this out! updated the snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, seems brilliant. But one case that I'm still figuring out, which if the translations variable is null, it won't be even pass the first if statement, as it will throught can't read property 'en' of null. Any suggestion on how to overcome that?

Comment: I thought to check for !translations at a high level and just localStorage.setItem directly, but then will lead to the same issue again.

Comment: The error will also through at translations[lang] = data as if translations is null

Comment: Hey @AbdalrhmanUsama, i found the time to look into it once again. I updated my answer after finding out the cause of the error you mentioned. Translations can only be applied in the callback of the ajax call, otherwise the code executes before the translations have been received.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, thanks a lot @HansSpieß !